Reference File 403s even on 777 permissions in CPanel
My master index.php is referencing a file, the path looks like this reference/send_email.php. I'm getting a 403 error trying to load that file in the Inspect tool. But without changing any permissions I'm able to load reference/index.css and reference/contactForm.js which are also both located in the reference folder. Regardless, I've changed the permissions for EVERYTHING inside public_html in CPanel to 777, but I'm still getting a 403.
I've seen a lot of talk about SELinux in my search to figure this stuff out, but I have no idea how to run command line prompts inside CPanel.
Quick edit: I've also seen a lot of talk around .htaccess but as far as I can tell, I don't have one? I've revealed hidden files, etc, but there isn't one there. I've tried adding it and the whole site gives a 400 error when I do that.

You can try to clear of the code inside reference/send_email.php and then check if you can load it. Maybe inside the file there is  code to check user permission.
